# fadeIn/out many (20 or so) items simultaneously causing huge performance hits. Solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a site I am working on for a large client that has a blurred cityscape background image which then has around 20 or so  elements of simulated flickering lights in the background. While I understand that performance of fading can chug I figured 19 elements would not be too bad. I was wrong.

As it stands right now each element recursively handles its sparkling like this:

```
function sparkle(flag, time) {
    if (flag) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.fadeIn(getRandomInt(250,1000), function () {
                sparkle(!flag, getRandomInt(250,1000));
            });
        }, time);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.fadeOut(getRandomInt(250,1000), function () {
                sparkle(!flag, getRandomInt(250,1000));
            });
        }, time
    }
}
```

when I run 20 of these all going at different rates the performance hit is extreme. Problem is this site has to go down to IE7( we have a custom fadein/out function for this) so I am left with few options.

My immediate answer is im going to check for css opacity transition support and convert the fade in and out to css transitions where available which should be a lot faster in modern browsers (and have them just turn on/off in ie7 with no fade). I was wondering if there is some way to optimize the original style to make it execute much faster. I am assuming its the excessive number crunching and callbacks being done per element to determine the fade rate over time thats responsible for the performance hits. Is there anyway to have one element doing the fading that the rest can base off of on their own offset (if that makes sense)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to eliminate recursion.

Comment: fadeIn and fadeOut differ though it is a bit sloppy

Comment: This shouldn't normally be a problem, are you sure the timeouts don't make these functions execute thousands of times? Place a console.log inside the function and see how often it logs,

Comment: @akonsu It isn't really recursive. The functions that call `sparkle()` are invoked after a time. The `sparkle()` function just schedules those unnamed functions to run. If it directly ran them, it would be recursion.

Comment: Try selecting one random number for each of the 20 and passing it around instead of recalculating a random repeatedly. Also using two functions `sparkleIn()` and `sparkleOut()` that get called back and forth would reduce the overhead a little.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after testing further its not even linked to fadeIn or out but rather the multiple large transparent images being present period is causing the slowdown. Its an entirely different problem so I will post it as a new question. Thank you all for the responses.